# Average of float[] array (Intel 8086)

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm trying to combine my ANSI C code with ASM (TASM to be precise) module.
I decided to choose the classic task - get average of numbers in array, and it is almost working, it compiles and links successfully, but at the end it says that average equals -0 (when it does not).

What did I do wrong? Here's the needed part of my **.c** code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern float avg(int, float*);

int main()
{
  int n = 2;
  float tab[] = {2.0, 3.0};
  printf("%.3g\n", avg(n, tab));

  return 0;
}
```

And **.asm** procedure:

```
avg PROC
    finit
    push BP
    mov BP, SP

    push bx
    mov cx, [bp+4]      ; no of elements
    mov bx, [bp+8]      ; address

    fldz ; zero
    jcxz avg_end ; if cx==0, end

    iter:
    fadd DWORD PTR [bx]
    add bx, 4
    loop iter

    fidiv DWORD PTR [bp+4] ; sum/n

    avg_end:
    pop bx
    pop BP
    ret
avg ENDP
```

My program has also one more extern function inside and it works well.
The only problem has to be inside `avg PROC` code. I'd appreciate your ideas!

Comment: Why 8 is added to `bx`? Are you sure `float` in your environment is 8 bytes?

Comment: Are you actually writing a 16-bit DOS program? If so, why?

Comment: Using offset 4 between arguments in 16-bit environment also looks weird. Are you sure it is along your ABI?

Comment: Oh, @MikeCAT. That's the first thing. You're right. It should be 4 I guess. Changed - it still does not give correct answer. But thanks, of course.

Comment: (I suspect that the problem is you're leaving the result of the calculation in the wrong place, but without knowing what ABI you *mean* to be using, I can't tell for sure or be any more help.)

Comment: Well, I'm completely new. Yes, I do actually write a 16-bit DOS program. It is **Intel 8086** architecture, under DOSBox. It's because I'm learning this one in school and I want to practice now when I'm bored. Does it make our situation more clear now?

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It seems I had two problems there:

- First of all - addressing.
  `bx` register should be filled with `[bp+6]` instead of `[bp+8]`.
  That's obvious, because my first arg is integer, 2B long, isn't it?
- In addition to that, **@Sep Roland** was right with my `fidiv` instruction.
  My value is not even DWORD, it's only WORD and it fixes all my problems.

It works now, thank you all for your time.
I couldn't delete my question, so I'm posting my answer, maybe it'll be useful someday.

Answer (score 3):

In the real address mode a pointer won't be just an offset. So to fetch the 2nd argument *float** you would need:

```
lds bx, [bp+8]      ;full pointer
```

You might want to `push ds`/`pop ds`.

Is the 1st argument even a dword? You might try:

```
fidiv WORD PTR [bp+4] ; sum/n
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you never popping anything from the FP stack?

You are at least missing a final `fstp DWORD PTR [bp]` prior to returning. Respectively whereever your ABI wants the return value written to.

Currently you are pushing to the FP stack, calculating the average, and that's it. You've leaked a register and never looked at the result.

Comment: As far as I know, if I return float value, the result should be placed on the top of the FPU stack `st(0)`. Isn't it like that?

Comment: Depends on the ABI your compiler chose. `hardfp` vs. `softfp`. The later one passes parameters and return values on the regular stack/registers, the first one pushes and expects all FP parameters and return value on the FP stack. Only in the `cdecl` ABI, `st(0)` is used to return.